# How use select * with group by subquery in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I have table of employees salary details records with columns

```
Id  Name        Year    Month   Salary
1   ABC         2021    Jan     50000
2   PQR         2021    Jan     40000
3   KLM         2021    Feb     45000
4   LMN         2021    Jan     55000
5   LMN         2022    Jan     20000
6   ABC         2022    Feb     25000
7   ABC         2022    Jan     2500
8   ABC         2022    Dec     60000
9   LMN         2022    Nov     70000
```

Now I want to find which employee gets salary greater than 100000 from joining, and display employees all data

--find which employee gets more than 100000 salary till now

```
select  name,sum(salary) as AnnualSalary from tblEmpsalary
group by Name
having sum(Salary)>100000 --this query works
```

--but below query display no data , (I want to show all data of employee which gets more than 100000 total salary)

```
SELECT id, name,Month,Year, SUM(Salary) AS TotalSales
FROM tblEmpsalary
GROUP BY name,Id,Month,Year,Salary
having SUM(Salary)>100000;
```

Comment: Seems that the only column (other than the `SUM`) that should be in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` is `name`. For starters you are grouping on `ID` but all your `ID`s are distinct values, so you are aggregating 1 value; and the `SUM` of a single value, is the single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T.ID,T.Name,T.Year,T.Month,T.Salary
 FROM tblEmpsalary AS T
 JOIN
 (
   select  ID
   from tblEmpsalary
   group by ID
   having sum(Salary)>100000
 )AS X ON T.ID=X.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a window function for this**

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  Month,
  Year,
  TotalSales
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS TotalSales
    FROM tblEmpsalary e
) e
WHERE e.TotalSales > 100000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query where one query for grouping and another is joining for fetch employees details:

```
SELECT TS.id, TS.name, TS.Month,Year, TS.Salary, ATS.TotalSales FROM 
 (SELECT Month, Year, SUM(Salary) AS TotalSales 
 FROM tblEmpsalary 
 GROUP BY Month,Year,Salary
 HAVING SUM(Salary)>100000
 ) AS ATS
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEmpsalary TS on ATS.Month = TS.Month and ATS.Year = TS.Year
 ORDER BY TS.name, TS.Id, TS.Month, TS.Year, ATS.TotalSales
```